# Dynamic Schema name in SQL View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, table-valued-parameters

I have two datasets:

1. one is data about dogs [my data]
2. the second is a lookup table of matching keys [I have no control over this data]

The matching keys are updated regularly, and I want to create a View (or something that fulfills the same purpose) of the Dog dataset, which always joins on **the most recent** matching keys. Furthermore, I need to be able to reference it inline - *as though it was a table*.

The match updates in the lookup table are differentiated by their schema names, so to get the most recent, I just have to identify the latest schema name and swap it out of the query.

Given that both Views and Table Valued Functions prohibit dynamic SQL, and Stored Procedures can't be referenced like a table can be how can I achieve this in just SQL?

Comment: You cannot use dynamic SQL in a View, as a View can only consist of a `SELECT` statement; after all a `VIEW` is simply a pre-compile `SELECT` statement. The problem here appears to be the design of your database. Why are you creating new objects (a Schema and table) every time you update your data?

Comment: I'm not, that's the part of the database I don't have any control over.

Comment: You may need to create a job (maybe SQL Agent) which monitors for external changes and updates the view when needed or load copy of needed data into your database.

Comment: Either way, I'm afraid you can't achieve what you are after with "just SQL", you have to use Dynamic SQL to be able to query the correct table dynamically. Otherwise, if you can't, ideally the design of the database needs to be fixed.

Comment: By 'just SQL' I mean not having to use another programming language. Dynamic SQL would be fine if there was a way to integrate it with either views or TableValuedFunctions, but it doesn't appear that's the case.

Comment: You could use dynamic SQL within a Stored Procedure; but you would therefore need to have an SP for each interaction you need with the database.

Answer (score 3):

> The match updates in the lookup table are differentiated by their schema names, so to get the most recent, I just have to identify the latest schema name and swap it out of the query.

You can use a view to solve this problem, but you need some way of altering it whenever new data is entered into the database.

I'm assuming that whenever a new schema is created, a new table is also created in that schema, but the table name and it's column names are always the same. Note that this assumption is critical to the solution I'm about to propose - and that solution is to use a DDL trigger listening to the `create_table` event on the database level to alter your view so that it will reference the schema of the newly created table.

Another assumption I'm making is that you either already have the initial view, or that you are working with SQL Server 2016 or higher (that allows create or alter syntax).

So first, let's create the initial view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.TheView 
AS 
    SELECT NULL As Test 
GO
```

Then, I've added the DML trigger, which creates and executes a dynamic `alter view` statement based on the schema of the newly created table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AlterViewWhenSchemaChanges
    ON DATABASE
    FOR CREATE_TABLE
AS

    DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max),
            @NewTableName sysname,
            @NewSchemaName sysname;
            
    SELECT  @NewSchemaName = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]',  'NVARCHAR(255)'),
            @NewTableName = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]',  'NVARCHAR(255)');

    -- We only want to alter the view when this specific table is created!
    IF @NewTableName = 'TableName' 
    BEGIN 

        SELECT @Sql = 
        'ALTER VIEW dbo.TheView
        AS
            SELECT Col as test
            FROM '+ QUOTENAME(@NewSchemaName) +'.'+ QUOTENAME(@NewTableName) +';'

        EXEC(@Sql)
    END
GO
```

This way, whenever a new table with the specific name (`TableName` in my example) is created, the view gets altered to reference the last `TableName` created (which is obviously created in the newest schema).

Testing the script:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TheView;
GO
```

Results:

```
Test
NULL
```

Create a new schema with the table `TableName`

```
CREATE SCHEMA SchemaName
CREATE TABLE SchemaName.TableName (Col int);

GO  

-- insert some data
INSERT INTO SchemaName.TableName(Col) VALUES (123);

-- get the data from the altered view
SELECT * FROM dbo.TheView
```

Results:

```
test
123
```

[You can see a live demo on Rextester.](https://rextester.com/XABK59289)